# custom formatting macro: need to print single digit integers with a decimal point

Tags: excel, formatting, custom-formatting, vba

Im working on a wee macro to output files as a prn which will be used as an input for other software. I've had everything working properly, the only problem is that the other software requires all the integers to be printed with a decimal point.

Using excel 2007 btw

Ie if the cell value is 0 it should be printed as "0." not blank. likewise if the value is 8, it should be printed as "8." this isnt a problem with most of the values as the vast majority are like 123.45765 etc.

The code tells me its expecting a ) after the decimal point in .NumberFormat(""0."") on line 4

```
Windows("bdf_generator").Activate
With Worksheets(2).Range("E2:H9592").FormatConditions _
.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, "=0", "=9")
FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat=(""0."")
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, the line `FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat=(""0."")` is incorrect due to the two double quotes (`""`) surrounding `0.`.
Also note that `FormatConditions(1).NumberFormat = "0."` should be prepended with `Selection.` or else it would throw an error in runtime.
Try this instead, as I believe it is clearer (and you get intellisense):

```
Windows("bdf_generator").Activate
Dim r As Excel.Range
Set r = Worksheets(2).Range("E2:H9592")
Dim fc As Excel.FormatCondition
Set fc = r.FormatConditions.Add(xlCellValue, xlBetween, "=0", "=9")
fc.NumberFormat = "0."
fc.StopIfTrue = False
```

Comment: you sir, are a champ. I'm eternally grateful and indebted to you. Should you need any help with whisky choice, or stress analysis, let me be your fisrt port of call.

Comment: The only minor edit it needed was a r.FormatConditions.Delete below set r. Upon checking the conditional formatting rules for the new sheet, I could see that there were artifacts from the source wbs, which i presume must have been taking precedence over the new format rules.